# Long polling vs server events in context of mobile device and data usage

Tags: android, push-notification

Trying to decide on which protocol to use in my Android application.
Doing research I see that long polling is more resource-intensive on server side because of constant reconnects. But it happens every 2 minutes or so.

With server events - connection happens once and events being constantly sent to client (Android) - hence data usage.

I also read people having problems with server events on 3G networks, when networks switch, etc

I also wonder if data usage will be any different between server events and long polling? With long polling every 2 minutes set of headers will be sent. But with server events - something on a wire every 3 seconds.

Question is.. What Google themselves uses?

> An FCM implementation includes an app server that interacts with FCM
>   via HTTP or XMPP protocol, and a client app. You can compose and send
>   messages using the app server or the Notifications console.

Ok, but what is `HTTP` protocol in this case?

Comment: I recommend you  using SignalR , it will choose what is the best protocol for you and it is very fast and reliable and also it has a great library for android